# how to update badge value on tab in Android?

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

I have `tabbar` with 5 tabs and i have added badge on my 4th tab. i want to update my badge value after some operation perform with the server. but don't know how can do this. Also i want update badge value from different `activities`.
snippet of code adding badge on `Tabbar`

```
TabWidget tabs = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
badge = new BadgeView(context, tabs, 3);
badge.setTextSize(12);
badge.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
badge.setText(pref.getString("balance", "0"));
badge.toggle();
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Hi Sangram Patil, can you post sample code here to add the badge in tabs, and which library(.jar) file you are using ? give me link for that library file

Comment: here is the sample code. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: I tried that once, but when I set the Image in tabs background as setIndicator(view) then badge is not display properly.... is any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create static `TabWidget` object tab in `TabActivity` like this,

```
public static TabWidget tabs;
```

Access the `tabs` object from any activity after your operations performs, update your `balance` in `SharedPreferences`. and use following code snippet.

In your other `Activity`.

```
TabWidget tabs = TabActivity.tabs;
badge = new BadgeView(context, tabs, 3);
badge.setTextSize(12);
badge.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
badge.setText(pref.getString("balance", "0"));
badge.toggle();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Pleasure is All mine.. happy coding  :)

Answer (score 0):

To save the shared preference you have to do it like this. Sort of like how you loaded it. You need to use the same preferences.

```
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREF_KEY", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("balance", balance_value);
        editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Share some of my try

If your view is layout like this

```
android:layout_width="0dp"<br>
android:layout_height="wrap_content"<br>
android:layout_weight="1"<br>
```

`BadgeView` wil blank your view.

How to slove? patch

```
android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener
```

like this :-

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = container.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        container.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        int width  = container.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = container.getMeasuredHeight(); 

        LayoutParams params = target.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height - BadgeView.this.getHeight();
        target.setLayoutParams(params);             
    } 
});
```